# Using state to dynamically display count aware div

Tags: reactjs

I want to dynamically display a div by calling a function `renderDiv(num)` where `num` will be the respective number of the div. So if I press a button, which calls the renderDiv method, a div should appear with text '1' and if I press the button again another div should appear where the first div should say '1' but the second div should say '2'. I am using a counter right now stored in the state.

```
<button onClick={this.renderDiv(this.state.numDivs)}>Add Div</button>
```

But when I click the button again the first Div also gets the updated variable and both the div show '2'. This is a small problem but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Sounds like a closure issue. can you show the `renderDiv` function? also add the `render` function.

Comment: That's very trivial. `Return(<p>${num}</p>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different take. Changing numDivs will cause your component to re-render which will result in the same result I think you're going for:

```
class Blah extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { numDivs: 0 };
  }

  renderDivs() {
    let divs = [];   
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.numDivs; i++) {
      divs.push(<div key={i}>Div {i+1}</div>);
    }

    return divs;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.setState({numDivs: this.state.numDivs+1}); }}>Add</button>
       {this.renderDivs()}
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rest of what your code looks like, I would do something like this. This lets you use the `index` on an array as the counter rather than using a numerical counter to count your divs:

```
class DivRenderer extends Component {

  state = { divs: [] }

  addDiv = () => {
    const { divs } = this.state;

    this.setState({ divs: [...divs, {}] });
  }

  render() {
    const { divs } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {divs.map((div, index) => (<div>{index + 1}</div>)}
        <button onClick={this.addDiv}>Add Div</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```